# Problem catching SqlException 547 with DeleteConfirmed class in ASP.NET Core MVC Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have standard MVC Controller on simple database table (`Products`) with corresponding `Model` and all Views (`Index, Detail, Edit and Delete`).
All functionalities works without problem if record doesn't have foreign key constraint.

I've modified `DeleteConfirmed` class in my Controller so I can catch `SqlException` that happens when someone tries to delete record that has foreign key constraint.

Here is my `DeleteConfirmed` class in Controller now:

```cs
// POST: Products/Delete/5
[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
{
    try
    {
        var products = await _context.Products.FindAsync(id);
        _context.Products.Remove(products);   
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));             
    }
    catch (SqlException ex) when (ex.Number == 547)
    {
        return Content("Product cannot be deleted because...");
    }    
}
```

But it still throws exception:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
> SqlException: The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE
> constraint "FK_...". The conflict occurred in
> database "Store", table "...", column
> '...'. The statement has been terminated.

Raw exception details shows that it's really exception 547:

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): The DELETE
> statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "...". The conflict
> occurred in database "Store", table "...", column '..'. The statement
> has been terminated.    at
> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.<>c.b__164_0(Task`1
> result) ... ... **Error Number:547,State:0,Class:16**

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong is the logic of your code.

Exceptions are supposed to be **exceptional**, not something that you expect to happen in the normal flow of your application. A foreign-key violation is something you would expect as a matter of course, hence not an exception.

So, instead of waiting for the exception to happen and reacting to it, be **proactive** by checking to see if the `Product` that is to be deleted has a foreign-key relationship with another entity. If so, don't try to do the delete, and show your "Product cannot be deleted" message.

Comment: I will do that, and it will solve the problem. But why can't I have simple text message displayed instead of known exception?

Comment: But if you check the product has not any relationship and before try to delete it another process add a relationship with the product. Wouldn't you get the exception? So you are making an extra query and you will not be sure you will can delete it.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to Delete the record from a Table which has a reference in another Table.

When you try to delete a row from **Products** Table, it comes to know that the same row has some related row in another Table (it says the name of this 2nd table at the end of the "FK_Products_(...)" exception error.

So, you need to delete from the 2nd Table first and then delete from **Product** table.

Comment: Sorry that my answer was not helpful, I didn't realize your question's focus was on the exception and not on the constraint itself

Comment: I didn't give you -1 , and I think your answer is also helpful.